# open activity above lockscreen

Tags: android

I've tried opening an `Activity` on the lock screen in `Android Pie` but I could not.
I added the `showWhenLocked` and `turnScreenOn` on the Android Manifest and on the proper activity and permissions I searched for but could not make the activity open on the default lock screen on the phone. Some help?

MainActivity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
        setShowWhenLocked(true);
        setTurnScreenOn(true);
    } else {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

Android Manifest

> android:showWhenLocked="true" 
>               android:turnScreenOn="true" 
>               android:showOnLockScreen="true" 
>               android:excludeFromRecents="true"

Comment: Improve your question and Share your code here Whatever u have already trying. Please check this  link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 12):

Here is my working method call it from onCreate() before setContentView() of activity

Also set below flag for your activity in AndroidManifest file.

```
android:showOnLockScreen="true"
```

/**
 * Allow calling screen to display over lock screen
 */

```
private fun allowOnLockScreen() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        setShowWhenLocked(true)
        setTurnScreenOn(true)
        val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
        keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
    } else {
        this.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not work for me. Some of the LayoutParams are deprecated in API 26-27. I researched and said to use setShowWhenLocked (true) setTurnScreenOn (true) but it does not work for me, too.

Comment: @GleysonAbreu i have changed method implementation. please check if it may help you

Answer (score 1):

Just override the following method in your activity which you want to open on the lock screen.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

And add the following tag to your activity in Manifest.

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Comment: Not work for me. Some of the LayoutParams are deprecated in API 26-27. I researched and said to use setShowWhenLocked (true) setTurnScreenOn (true) but it does not work for me, too.

Comment: Hey did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
PowerManager.WakeLock cpuWakelock = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "XXX:CPU_WAKE_LOCK");
cpuWakelock.acquire();
```